# sql server query with multiple where's

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working with a database that has multiple machines writing to it, each machine is identified by a column called ControllerID, so for example, One machine could have a controllerID of 20 and one could be 30 ext

What i want to do is for each machine get the elapsed time between the last reading and now. This is what i currently have:

```
SELECT     TOP (1) controllerID, convert(Datetime,ReaderTime), DATEDIFF(SECOND,dtReading,GETDATE())
FROM         ReaderData
WHERE     (controllerID = '30') AND (CardID = 'FFFFFFF0  ')
ORDER BY ReaderIndex DESC
```

This gets the Elapsed seconds between the last reading and now, but if i put AND (controllerID = 'Another ID') obviously that wont work as and OR also does not work as it just picks the last one, How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If have understood your goal correctly, you need something like

```
select
    controllerID,
    max(convert(datetime, ReaderTime)),
    datediff(ss, max(dtReading), getdate())
from ReaderData
where CardID = 'FFFFFFF0  '
group by controllerID
```

This will give you information about last `ReaderTime` and difference from last `dtReading` to now for each `controllerID`.

UPDATE:

*On a side note, if i wanted to compare the last 2 records for each controllerID how could i do that...*

Well, as "quick-and-dirty" solution you cant do following: get results from previous query and outer apply previous by time interval record like this:

```
select 
    T.controllerID,
    datediff(ss, T.Max_dtReading, T1.Max_dtReading)
from 
    (
        select
            controllerID,
            max(dtReading) as Max_dtReading
        from ReaderData
        where CardID = 'FFFFFFF0  '
        group by controllerID
    ) as T
    outer apply(
        select max(T1.dtReading) as Max_dtReading
        from ReaderData as T1
        where 
            T1.CardID = 'FFFFFFF0  '
            and T1.controllerID = T.controllerID
            and T1.dtReading < T.Max_dtReading
    ) as T1
```

Comment: That works perfectly thank you, On a side note, if i wanted to compare the last 2 records for each controllerID how could i do that, so the DtReading from the last records minus the Dtreading from the records before to get the elapsed time between records?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use OR in the way I think you do, you need to group the OR's in ()s as below.

```
       SELECT     TOP (2) controllerID, convert(Datetime,ReaderTime), DATEDIFF(SECOND,dtReading,GETDATE())
        FROM         ReaderData
        WHERE     (controllerID = '30' OR controllerID = '31' OR controllerID = '32') AND CardID = 'FFFFFFF0  '
        ORDER BY ReaderIndex DESC
GROUP BY ControllerID
```

Answer (score 0):

did you want to use `IN`()?

```
SELECT     TOP (1) controllerID, convert(Datetime,ReaderTime), DATEDIFF(SECOND,dtReading,GETDATE())
FROM         ReaderData
WHERE     (controllerID in( '30','26')) AND (CardID = 'FFFFFFF0  ')
ORDER BY ReaderIndex DESC
```